# webbrowser.document javascript vb6

Tags: javascript

I could do with help here...

```
<div id="content">

    <div class="ltFlt fullWidth vsp20">

      <br></br>   
      <div class="ltFlt fullWidth vsp20">
          <h2 class="greyBg"><b>TEKLİF TEMEL VERİLERİ</b>
              <span class="sp50"  style="width:400px;">
                  <a href="#" onclick="fuOnedit('coredata'); return false">
                      <b>Değiştir</b>
                  </a>
              </span>
          </h2>
      </div>

      <div class="fntfmt vsp10 width232">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="750">
              <tr>
```

So in this case,  I want to click on "Değiştir" link which calls this code:

```
onclick="fuOnedit('coredata'); return false"
```

How can I do that ? I need to call javascript code. I tried this one but it didn't work:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow ("fuOnedit('coredata'); return false")
```

Comment: Why not just have the function return false?  Also, do you have any js code or are you asking for some?

Comment: Justin, 
Dude when I tried  `WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow ("fuOnedit('coredata')")`,   

it didn't work either and says: 

`Run-time error '-2147352319 (80020101)':

Method 'parentWindow' of object 'JScripTypeInfo' failed`

Comment: Yes,I found it indeed.. I just needed to put there Call:)
  
`Call WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow.execScript("fuOnedit('coredata');")`